# Delete multiple nodes from Firebase Realtime DB with NodeJS

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following code:

```
poolPlayersRef.child(currPool).once('value', function(playerSnapshot) {         
   
    // Iterate to get all the players
    playerSnapshot.forEach(function(childSnap) {                

        playersInPoolRef.child(childSnap.key).child(currPool).remove().then(function() {
            
            // Display confirmation
            // Now remove from the pool player list as well
            poolPlayersRef.child(currPool).child(childSnap.key).remove().then(function() {
                
                // Display confirmation

            }).catch(function(error) {     
                   
                console.log("PoolPlayersRef Remove Failed:" + error.message);                          

            });                    

        }).catch(function(error) {     
               
            console.log("PlayersInPoolRef Remove Failed:" + error.message);                
  
        });                

    });

}).then(function() {                

    // Now remove from the pool player list as well
    poolsRef.child(currPool).remove().then(function() {
        
        //DISPLAY CONFIRMATION MESSAGE                    

    }).catch(function(error) {                    

        console.log("DELETE POOL Failed:" + error.message);                    

    });

}).catch(function(error) {                

    console.log("PoolPlayersRef Node Read Failed:" + error.message);            

});
```

And what I would like it to do it read from the poolPlayersRef node and for every player remove the entry. then also remove the associated playersInPoolRef entry in this node.

Once all the children are deleted, then delete the poolRef.

My code works in that it goes one by one to remove the players in both the PoolPlayersRef and PoolPlayersRef BUT the deletion of the Pool happens immediately and i would prefer that it only gets deleted after all the entries in the above nodes is completed.

Can someone recommend how to fix my code!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is to gather the promises that are returned by the `remove` calls, and then return all of them in a `Promise.all`:

```
poolPlayersRef.child(currPool).once('value', function(playerSnapshot) {                
    let promises = []
    playerSnapshot.forEach(function(childSnap) {                
        promises.push(playersInPoolRef.child(childSnap.key).child(currPool).remove());
    });
    return Promise.all(promises);
}).then(function() {                
    return poolsRef.child(currPool).remove();
}).catch(function(error) {                
    console.log("PoolPlayersRef Node Read Failed:" + error.message);            
});
```

Comment: your soln only includes two deletes, the code i have has three deletes in it. also u have a type `let promises = p[]` should be `let promises = [];` How do i account for the other delete of `poolPlayersRef.child(currPool).child(childSnap.key).remove()`?

Comment: Sorry that I missed one of your deletes. You should be able to add that remove to the array of promises too. Did you try that?

Comment: would it be a separate array for those promises or in the same array?

Comment: Just a single array seems fine here. If that doesn't work, edit your question to show what you tried please.

Comment: so i just basically added the same loop ` playerSnapshot.forEach(function(childSnap) {                
    
   promises.push(poolPlayersRef.child(currPool).child(childSnap.key).remove());
    
 });` is that how you would have solved this as well?